# Android media player - How to switch between videos?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, android-videoview

I am developing an application in which I want to show videos. Here my requirement is, I should be able to play video for while (say video A for 2 min) then I will switch to video B for another 15 seconds and then again I will switch back to video A. But whenever I switch back to video A, it should start from where it was stopped previously.

My questions are

1. How can I achieve the switching between video?
2. How can achieve the tagging for the video A for resuming from the previously paused time?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the videos by keeping two MediaPlayers and switching between them.
You prepare the second one seek it and when the time is right you switch them out.
The code below is for the same thing except I use it on user interaction.
(you can ignore the AssetFileDesciptor as it's the way I open videos).

```
videoPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = ExpansionFiles.SharedSingleton().getZipAssetFileDescriptorForFile("video" + camera + ".mp4", context);
if ( descriptor != null ) {
    try {
        videoPlayer2.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        videoPlayer2.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    videoPlayer2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoPlayer2.start();
            videoPlayer2.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoPlayer.setDisplay(null);
                    videoPlayer2.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    videoPlayer2.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                            if ( videoPlayer2 != null && videoPlayer != null ) {
                                videoPlayer = videoPlayer2;
                                videoPlayer2 = null;
                            }
                        }
                    });



                }
            });
            videoPlayer2.seekTo(videoPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    });
```

Comment: where should I put these code?

Comment: You use this when you want to change videos.

Answer (score 1):

> How can achieve the tagging for the video A for resuming from the previously paused time?

You can do a [`seekTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#seekTo%28int%29) to jump to a particular position. But the problem here is that you should wait for the `seekTo()` to complete. And Android does not provide such a callback for the VideoView.

So instead I suggest that you go for Vitamio's [VideoView](http://vov.io/vitamio/api/io/vov/vitamio/widget/VideoView.html)

Comment: Hi Reno, Thanks for your reply. I have one more question.

Comment: Since I am developing the custom media player, so I want to have control over the android basic media player. Vitamio doesn't give that flexibility i guess?. So have decide to customize the default android player. Here my question is, Can we switch between the stream while playing?. For ex: currently my media player playing a video from stream A and then after some time i want the same media player instance(I don't want to create new instance of media player) to play a video from stream B. Is this possible? If possible how can i achieve that?